# Which is the best way to show a loading sign to the fragment when data loading?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

We use <kbd>viewpager</kbd> fragment in it, we want to show every single page when <kbd>viewpager</kbd> show a fragment and load data , because it saves memory a lot, but we can not show a sign for loading when data loading, we replace a fragment when asynctask's `onPreExecute` calls and we replace again when calls `onPostExecute`, but there is some thing wrong, which is the best way to show loading sign when data loading?

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
    private FragmentManager manager = null;

    private class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_container, new LoadingFragment())
                    .commit();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_container, new ContentFragment())
                    .commit();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    public TestFragment(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
        this.manager = supportFragmentManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new TestTask().execute();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_page, null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another easy way if you use the action bar in your app is calling `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);` in the FragmentActivity right after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and from the child fragment `((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(visibility);` will show or hide a progress bar in the action bar of your hosting activity depending on your progress in the `AsyncTask`.

Note: I'm using  support appcompat, but I'm pretty sure the methods are the same if you use ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: thank you, but I didn't quite understand what you mean, is there a sample code for this implementation?

Comment: Take a look here : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html#actionbar_actionview . Let me know if you have any other questions. The approach described basically shows a progress bar in the right corner of the action bar without any other fragment or code necessary. Many apps I've seen uses it (The Verge for example).

Answer (score 1):

add an progressbar to  the layout of the fragment but defining it invisible and centering it both vertically and  horizontally. then in the onPreExecute set the visibility of all other views to Visibility.GONE and set the progressbar to VISIBLE. reverse this in the onPostExecute() method!

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, do you think this is the best solution? is the any other way to replace the fragment when the loading done?

Comment: in my thoughts yes! i wouldn't personally think of any other way!